# What encryption do I have to use with openssl?

Tags: linux, openssl

I would like to create a SSL certificate for my server(apache), i'm following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL

My question is: what is the stronger encryption to create a key with openssl?

Thank you

Comment: Just make sure that you are aware of this: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/19/beast_exploits_paypal_ssl

Comment: openssl seems does not support TLS 1.2 (because I also need a certificate for my mail server)

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole section about creating self-signed certificates on the page you linked, just follow it.

The guide uses RSA encryption. 2048-bit for the CA certificate and 1024-bit server certificate. I'd maybe use 2048-but for both.

If it's a high traffic or commercial site, I'd definitely consider a commercial server certificate from an acknowledged CA, since using a self-signed certificate will generate those ugly red errors you might see in Chrome or Firefox sometimes. In no browser you will get that yellow or green lock icon in the URL bar.